# Django Heroku CreateView Post Bad Request 500 in Production only

Tags: django, heroku, django-views, django-generic-views

I'm deploying a Django App live for the first time, and everything has gone relatively smoothly so far. My site works fine, except for one CreateView (EstRequestCreateView) that works locally, but when I try to create new Estimate Request in Production I receive a Bad Request (500) response. I've added some print statements to the code just to identify where it's failing, but it appears to be behind the scenes somewhere as it makes it all the way through both of my functions no problem.

Here is my View:

```
class EstRequestCreateView(CreateView):
    model = EstRequest
    # fields = ['market', 'builder', 'plan', 'due_date', 'notes']
    form_class = EstRequestModelForm
    template_name = 'requests/request_form.html'
    success_url = '/requests/'

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        if request.user.is_authenticated():
            print(request.POST)
            form = self.get_form()
            print('form')
            if form.is_valid():
                print('is_valid')
                return self.form_valid(form)
            else:
                print('not valid')
                return self.form_invalid(form)

    def form_valid(self, form):
        print('form_valid func')
        form.instance.added_by = self.request.user
        print('user')
        market = self.request.POST['market']
        print('market')
        note = self.request.POST['notes']
        print('notes')
        due_date = self.request.POST['due_date']
        print('duedate')
        form.instance.trello_id = create_card(market, note, due_date)
        print('trello created')
        return super(EstRequestCreateView, self).form_valid(form)
```

And here is my log in Heroku:

```
Dec 21 15:40:51 ao-prime app/web.1:  <QueryDict: {'csrfmiddlewaretoken': ['ympCUozBK7qYEoMHgAffBWCoQce7nrqC'], 'plan': [''], 'due_date': ['2016-12-26 18:40:39'], 'market': ['1'], 'builder': ['1'], 'notes': ['Test 1 with Logging']}> 
Dec 21 15:40:51 ao-prime app/web.1:  form 
Dec 21 15:40:51 ao-prime app/web.1:  is_valid 
Dec 21 15:40:51 ao-prime app/web.1:  form_valid func 
Dec 21 15:40:51 ao-prime app/web.1:  user 
Dec 21 15:40:51 ao-prime app/web.1:  market 
Dec 21 15:40:51 ao-prime app/web.1:  notes 
Dec 21 15:40:51 ao-prime app/web.1:  duedate 
Dec 21 15:40:51 ao-prime app/web.1:  creating card 
Dec 21 15:40:51 ao-prime app/web.1:  getting card values 
Dec 21 15:40:51 ao-prime app/web.1:  got card values 
Dec 21 15:40:51 ao-prime app/web.1:  got market 
Dec 21 15:40:51 ao-prime app/web.1:  params set 
Dec 21 15:40:51 ao-prime app/web.1:  request 
Dec 21 15:40:51 ao-prime app/web.1:  json created 
Dec 21 15:40:51 ao-prime app/web.1:  trello id 
Dec 21 15:40:51 ao-prime app/web.1:  trello created 
Dec 21 15:40:51 ao-prime heroku/router:  at=info method=POST path="/requests/create/" host=www.ao-prime.com request_id=8919f0d5-96f9-423f-b6c7-f7f10113368a fwd="74.218.177.46" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=483ms status=500 bytes=253
```

The only thing that is somewhat helpful coming from Heroku is the response 500. I've added the Print statements to make sure the functions I have defined are running at least up to the Return statements. I'm not sure what is wrong and I'm not sure how to debug this further. Like I said it's working perfectly in Test.

Can someone help me point out what I might be wrong? Or if not help me understand how I can debug production with more success. I tried adding the papertrail logging plugin to my Heroku app, but it appears to be the same log I have in Heroku. Any help would be greatly apprecaited! Thanks.

Edit: I guess I'll just use django-debug-toolbar

Comment: does your `DEBUG = True` in settings.py?

Comment: Nope, my production.py settings have DEBUG = False. I know my production.py settings are being imported because my DB settings are working. I can share my settings for Base, Development and Production if you think that will be useful.

Comment: Change `DEBUG`  on  `True`, than you'll have to receive full traceback of error

Comment: I'll give that a shot. Does it make sense to store Debug = True as an Env Var so I don't need to git push just to update Debug for testing?

Comment: @whieronymus, yes, load your debug setting from the environment.

Comment: Is that the only option for debugging in django? The debug stack doesn't normally point to the specific issue. It tells you which function failed but I dont see where it tells you the arguments that were passed into it.

Comment: @whieronymus, you might find the [`django-debug-toolbar`](https://github.com/jazzband/django-debug-toolbar) helpful.